# Mixed Synchronous and Asynchronous Loggers not working - log4j2

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j2

Using log4j2, I'm struggling to get a synchronous logger and a asynchronous logger working together.

Taking the example from here [Apache Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/manual/async.html) (under the heading Mixing Synchronous and Asynchronous Loggers) and running the application below will simply create the log file but write nothing to it. I'm also not sure of adding two loggers pointing at the same appender, but its the Apache documentation, so I'm assuming that's ok.

**LOG4J2 Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- No need to set system property "Log4jContextSelector" to any value
     when using <asyncLogger> or <asyncRoot>. -->

<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Async Loggers will auto-flush in batches, so switch off immediateFlush. -->
        <RandomAccessFile name="RandomAccessFile" fileName="asyncWithLocation.log"
                          immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %class{1.} [%t] %location %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- pattern layout actually uses location, so we need to include it -->
        <AsyncLogger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="RandomAccessFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Root level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="RandomAccessFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

***pom.xml***

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Application**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            logger.trace(String.format("Hello number %d", i));
        }
        LogManager.shutdown();
    }
}
```

However, if i change the log4j2 configuration and modify the loggers element to read the below i get the expected output in the log file.

```
<Loggers>
    <AsyncRoot name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="RandomAccessFile"/>
    </AsyncRoot>
</Loggers>
```

**What I need**

Ideally i want something like the following to work. However this configuration will only print out the lines to a console and create the log file but not write the contents to it. What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- No need to set system property "Log4jContextSelector" to any value
     when using <asyncLogger> or <asyncRoot>. -->

<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Async Loggers will auto-flush in batches, so switch off immediateFlush. -->
        <RandomAccessFile name="RandomAccessFile" fileName="asyncWithLocation.log"
                          immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %class{1.} [%t] %location %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!--write to file - i dont care when it happens-->
        <AsyncLogger level="trace" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="RandomAccessFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>

        <!--Async so the console messages appear in the order expected-->
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in first LOG4J2 Config the level of your root loggers is "info".
whereas in main method you are doing logger.trace().
Refer doc: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/architecture.html

Where they represent level orders.

In case `Asyncroot` you changed level to "trace". That is why it's working.
And again when you are adding appender as console then you are having level="trace".

You are getting root logger because there is no logger name "HelloWorld", by default it will give you root logger.

Try using logger.info().

Comment: I'm not sure i totally understand. Using the first config yields no lines in the log file, regardless of the root level being at info would the AsyncLogger not log records to the log file? To re-iterate: Im not getting any logs recorded.

Comment: Using first config as it is, replace logger.trace(String.format("Hello number %d", i)) in main method by logger.info(String.format("Hello number %d", i)). Then you getting your logs in file?